# How to access variables values (observations) in a data file using variable names in python

Tags: python, file, variables

I wanted to have some education on how do we access the variable values(observation for a particular variable in a file using the variable names.

So my question is this:

Suppose I have a file with four variables and the following example data.

```
ID  Name   Marks  Rank
1   Tom     76      3
2   Dick    95      2
3   Harry   97      1
```

Now instead of accessing the data values of each variable above by first removing the first line(Variable Name) using fob.readline() method and then iterating the remaining line using a for loop, I want to use the variable name present in the file to access the values for that variable.

So if I want to access '1' from the variable ID, can we do it by just using the variable name ID here using some function/method or a way?

I guess what I am trying to find out is that instead of reading each line of a data file and storing it as a list, is it possible to access the observation/records in a data file using just the variable names of that data?

Like in SAS or other statistical tool if I use the variable name in a SAS Data Step, we can access the values of that variable for each observation. So is it possible to access values of a variable using the variable name? Like ID[0] , ID[1] etc or anything similar can give us each observation value in that variable? I know ID[0], ID[1] etc wont work but this might give a drift what I am asking.

This actually helps as in a file with many variables we might want to use a variable name to access the data values in that file in case we are running any algorithm on that data.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the edit of table. I was doing just that when your edit helped.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you file really looks like

```
ID  Name   Marks  Rank
1   Tom     76      3
2   Dick    95      2
3   Harry   97      1
```

you can create a [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe) with [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)' [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv) function:

```
data = read_csv('your_data.txt', sep=r'\s+')
```

Now you can [access the values the easy way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html):

```
>>> data
   ID   Name  Marks  Rank
0   1    Tom     76     3
1   2   Dick     95     2
2   3  Harry     97     1
>>> data.Marks
0    76
1    95
2    97
Name: Marks
>>> data.Name[2]
'Harry'
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! I guess Pandas is the key for data analysis in Python. Just for an education, a few people had told me that if this needs to be done in core python without pandas then the only option is to convert it into a dictionary dict={"ID":[1,2,3],"Name":["Tom","Dick","Harry"]....}. So does the dictionary feature would be able to large number of records(~10MMobservations)? How efficient and fast would the dictionary would be on such data?

Comment: @ Dominic 

Hi,Any thoughts on how efficient would the dictionary object be if the no.of observations are in MM.Some estimate of how much processing time dict might take if analyzed a data set of around a MM or more observations.

Comment: @Manish for situations where the data set is large you shouldn't use Python's built-in dictionaries when Pandas is available.  Pandas is optimized for those use cases and, I believe, will be less memory intensive as well as much faster

Comment: Thanks @sequenceGeek.  Any idea how large the dataset we can safely take while doing operations in dict. I am trying to better educate myself of the cons of using dict and when not to use it. Thanks